# AngularJs dropdown added dynamically issue with model updation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am adding dropdown on click of a button . The Model of these dropdowns are same when I am adding it to DOM .

There is a list of items which is creating dropdowns using ng-repeat .
This list of items are pushed with new item on button click .

Now while adding a new dropdown to the list the model is the same everytime

when I change any drop downs , it is changing all others also .

What I am looking for :

When I add a new item to the list , (that item will be shown as a dropdown on UI using ng-repeat) although the model of the item being added in the list are same, items selected in one dropdown should not reflect in other.

I understand MVC and how model updates views in angular. 
This might be simple , However I am finding it tough for now.

Please provide your valuable help.

```
<div style="border:5px solid grey;" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
 <div ng-repeat="li in list track by $index">

  <span ng-bind-html="li"></span>

 </div>

<input type="button" ng-click="addNewDropDown()" value="Add New Dropdown">

</div>
```

And app code is :

```
(function (){
var app = angular.module('ruleApp', []);

app.config(['$sceProvider', function($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
}]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.names=['a','b','c','d'];
var dropdown="<select><option ng-repeat="+"x in names"+">{{x}}</option></select>";
$scope.list=[dropdown];
$scope.addNewDropDown=function(){   
    var newDD="<select><option ng-repeat="+"x in names"+">{{x}}</option></select>"; 
    $scope.list.push(newDD);
};  
});


})()
```

Comment: please post your code what you have tried in plunkr will be helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: Welcome to the SO my friend, it's good to post your code with your question.

Comment: I have updtaed the question  and added code snippet . .

Comment: I found a similar issue later : (Please ,this is not dulcitae , just similar) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150903/dynamically-creating-multiple-dropdown-and-auto-setting-each-dropdown-in-angular